# centering image int floating div

Tags: html, css

I cannot center image in `div` that is floating left.
I have tried text-align and set margins.

CSS:

```
.to_left_690 {
    width: 690px;
    float: left;    
}
.to_left_290 {
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 14px 0px;
    text-align: justify;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="to_left_690">

<h3>Date Center</h3>

    <p>One of the biggest` data centers in Latin America with over 3000 servers took a proactive approach to monitor their electrical infrastructure. Over 4 years later they have still not had any major disruptions.</p>

<h3>Call Center</h3>

    <p>
        <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-181" alt="baloons" src="http://www.sheerdigitaltest.net/janus/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/baloons.png" width="62" height="70">During Carnival 2013 the data center air conditioning failed for a call centre company and no-one on site. Thanks to early detection and alerts sent to the standby maintenance team they were quickly able to resolve the situation and prevent a catastrophic shutdown.</p>

<h3>Facilities Management:</h3>

    <p><span>With over 1200 people working at headquarters the TJES needed a solution to maintain proper working conditions to be able to perform with the minimum of disruption. Janus Technology solutions have eliminated all problems and saved millions in lost productivity over 2 years</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="to_left_290">
    <img class="size-full wp-image-183 aligncenter" alt="ipad" src="http://www.sheerdigitaltest.net/janus/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ipad.png" width="290" height="368">fdsfdsfdsfds</div>
```

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLwSh/

Comment: In theory the img IS in the center. The div is 290px and the img is 290px and the div is floated to the left. The image will be to the left in this instance. Center the div or give the div 100% width and then the image will center.

Comment: You have the answers, you just need to decide whether you want fixed width floated div or center aligned image. You can only achieve one thing.

Answer (score 2):

add this to a class on the floated div:

```
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
```

it's not centering in the div now because <s>floated divs size to the width of their content</s> you set a fixed width on the div so the img is centered within the 290px you gave it, so the div isn't taking up the whole screen width

Answer (score 0):

Set image inside another div and use `display:inline` in image style.

Comment: Is there any other sollutions? I do not want adding one extra div.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want? [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/leoMestizo/DRxjB/)

Just add this CSS rule:

```
.to_left_290 {
    width: 100%; /* Instead of 290px */
    text-align: center;
}
```

BTW, you have to use `tex-align` property in the "container" element, not in the child (the follow CSS rules **NOT** center the inside `img`:

```
.to_left_290 > img {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Because you are telling that center the content inside the `img` element.

Comment: Because you have set the `width` of the `div.to_left_290` to 290px. If you change the value property to 100%, the div will fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you question is about centering the image in relation to page. The reason is you have the wrapper div `.to_left_290`  with `width: 290px;`. Because the image is wrapped within a container that has fixed with and `float:left` you can not expect it to align in the center of the page. You need 100% width for the wrapper class.

Not sure if you need the fixed width and float align for image wrapper, but if you do then you can not have the image aligned center of the page. If you can change that part here's something you can do.

Change the width of image wrapper `.to_left_290` to 100%. However, adding 100% width to the floated div eliminates the need of having a floated div. If you still want your div to be floated left and with fixed width, you can not have it centered.

Only thing you can do is to get rid of fixed width on a wrapper div. Like this:

```
.to_left_290 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gjmvY/1/